# Is there an equivalent of the spanish "que hueva" slang expression in English to denote that you feel lazy about doing something?

Tags: expressions, translation, loanwords, spanish

In Spanish slang, particularly in the west, the expressions "que hueva" or "me da hueva" are used, respectively, to convey that you are lazy about doing something. The context might be as follows:

A: "Do you want to play soccer?"
B: "Que hueva" [meaning something like "noo, feeling too lazy right now for that"]

In the latter case ("me da hueva") literally translates to "it gives me hueva" and is like saying that something (perhaps a homework assignment or menial task) "gives you" that lethargic feeling.

Are there possible equivalents in English or expressions/constructs similar to the above?

Comment: Actually, that’s Mexican slang, not Spanish slang.

Comment: qué hueva - This one is from Mexico - expression denoting a lack of interest or fatigue Source: http://www.speakinglatino.com/word/que-hueva/#ixzz27QJasver huevear: This one is from Chile - 1) screw around, mess around, in a positive sense 2) to bother, annoy Source: http://www.speakinglatino.com/the-most-important-word-in-chile/#ixzz27QJGe9KG

Comment: I could comment on this, but, 'frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn".        

:-). Akin to GBorreson's "can't be bothered".  
[See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankly,_my_dear,_I_don't_give_a_damn)

Comment: Is "hueva" derived from "egg" or "roe", as in *huevos rancheros*? Literally, then, *How's an egg* ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Can't be bothered" is an indication of laziness, but if you're feeling lazy and want to save on words, sometimes a simple "meh" will suffice.

Comment: good point on the "meh"

Comment: @tchrist ...nor the pronunciation.

Answer (score 10):

One that has gained currency in recent years, at least in the UK, is *Can't be arsed.*

Comment: Also, *can't be fucked*.

Answer (score 2):

"I don't feel like it" often means that I am too lazy to do it. Though that can also mean that you don't like doing this thing at all, and not just that you are too lazy/tired/whatever to do it at this paritcular moment.

Comment: Or similarly, "I'm not feeling it," meaning (approximately) "I don't feel inspired to do it."

Answer (score 0):

A phrase used in the US is *I wanna chill* or *I wanna [chill out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/chill-out#chill-out__2)*.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is called *getting the blahs,* or *feeling the blahs*.

A quick search on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=the+blahs) indicates the term is in fairly widespread use. One [blogger](http://www.cbn.com/spirituallife/Devotions/butler_blah.aspx) wrote:

> Did you know that the word “blah” is actually listed in the dictionary? Webster defines it as “a feeling of dullness, boredom, lethargy, likened to a winter's day.”

Not only that, you can even find lots of [tips](http://islandperspective.com/2010/10/27/12-things-you-can-do-to-beat-the-blahs/) for *beating the blahs*, too!

Answer (score 0):

How about: That's the last thing I feel like doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

The closest phrase that I can think of for "Que hueva" would be "What a drag".

A: "Do you want to play soccer?" B: "What a drag"

For "me da hueva" I would use "bums me out"

"Just thinking about homework bums me out"

It isn't literal but it does express the feeling of not wanting to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Also, good to know that the literal translation of the ‘hueva’ in this phrase is ‘balls’ as in ‘lazy, the way balls hang’. So you may want to consider this before using in a formal situation.